# How do I find the roots of $y=e^x-2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find the root of this: $y=e^x-2$.

I don't know how to find the roots of this function because I have two variables...
The teacher said the root is between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: The question is asking:  find all $x$ (presumably, real) such that $e^x-2=0$.

Comment: $y=e^x-2$ is an equation, not a function. What is the function ?

Comment: An equation can be defined in terms of a function and vice versa, y is a function of x, f(x)=RHS.

Answer (score 0):

When they talk about roots they want those $x$ values which makes $y=0$

So you want to find $x$ such that $$e^x -2 =0$$

That is solving $e^x=2$.

You can solve it by taking the natural logarithm of both sides.

Answer (score 0):

A root is any value of $x$ which gives $y = 0$. (Roots, solutions, and $x$-intercepts all mean the same thing.)

$$0 = e^x-2$$

$$e^x = 2 \implies x = \ln 2$$

At $x = \ln 2$, the graphs intersects the $x$-axis. Thus, it it the root of the function.

Answer (score 0):

There are two variables but one of them is dependent and one is independent: $y$ is a function of $x$ if you think about it, since varying the value of $x$ by choice will change the value which $y$ takes.

The roots of equation defined by a function in this way are the values of $x$ which mean that the function $y$ is equal to $0$, so just set $y$ equal to $0$, re-arrange and use an appropriate inverse function such that you end up with a value for $x$.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve it algebraically as above. There's also many  numerical approaches. Here's one.

Let $x_0$=1.

It can be shown that the sequence,  $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{e^{x_n}-2}{e^{x_n}}$, gets closer to the root for higher and higher iterations.

$x_{n+1}=x_n-1+\frac{2}{e^{x_n}}$

Comment: Why is there a need to use approximations when an exact answer is easily available?

Comment: Depends on the exercise I guess. Does the teacher want the solution in decimal form correct to 7 digits?